# Best audio/video solution for a site

Tags: flash, flash-media-server

I am wondering what is the best way to support audio/video chat on a community site. Couple of options that I am aware of:

1. FMS server
2. Java applet using sockets to directly connect both sender and receiver

What would you suggest? I know Google (Gmail Gtalk) installs some kind of an application. But is it possible to avoid the server completely and do a direct connection (to save my server bandwidth)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FMS is not peer to peer to this date, therefore you'll always pay for the bandwidth as long as you're not going P2P.

Flash Player 10 has these capabilities built in, but Adobe is yet to provide FMS that is P2P capable, beside the "hosted beta" called Stratus where Adobe makes even more confusion, making it unclear whether you can release a commercial application or not under the hosted Stratus server, rendering all these features useless (these are the "advantages" of proprietary, obscure protocols, close minded companies).

And that's FAR from being all that will stop you from investing your first $$$ in a FMS license! Beside the protocol issues, Adobe doesn't provide an open API Achoustic Echo Canceler within Flash making the audio communication extremely painful, unreliable, specially without headphones, not to mention the network latency causing seconds of audio delays. The [AEC is there](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-273), but it's only to be used by the Acrobat conference services (same for screen sharing).

I don't know about Java based solutions - I suppose you'll be hit by the poor JRE penetration on PCs nowadays and the long antipathy for applets but that might do better than anything from Adobe in the end!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Adobe Stratus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use a media server like FMIS from Adobe, Red5 or Wowza to handle all the audio/video chat and a Flash client to run in the browser and capture/display the audio/video.

You can also purchase a solution off the shelf like [AVChat 3](http://avchat.net/) that supports all 3 media servers: FMIS, Red5 and Wowza.

> is it possible to avoid the server completely and do a direct connection

Yes but the only media server that can do p2p is Flash Media Enterprise Server (different than FMIS) and that's very expensive. Also p2p is not so reliable trough firewalls and it's not good for many 2 many live video chat (only for one 2 one or one 2 many).